# How to view/convert to text a Maple script embedded in a mws file

Tags: maple, file-conversion

in a textbook, examples on the book companion website are given in Maple, using a .mws file format.

I do not have Maple but I am interested in studying the code of the examples.
I wonder if there is a conversion tool for Linux that allows me to export to text or at least to view the content of the script.

I am aware there exist a free Maple player but from the [product description](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/Mapleplayer/) it is not clear if it allows to see the script content or just "play" with the inputs it defines.

I did also try [this Maple-to-Python converter](https://github.com/davidovitch/maple-to-python), but it's very alpha and it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The Maple Player should definitely be able to open any .mws file. You won't be able to run commands, but you can at least read the code contained in the file.

Maple itself can export .mws files to text, but other than that, I haven't heard of any other converters for extracting the code from these files.

Comment: I haven't tried the Maple Player, but if it's just like viewing a Maple worksheet in regular Maple---just lacking the ability to execute---then you can simply copy-and-paste directly to plaintext form.